# validate sendKeys(input) of selenium Webdriver after enter

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to validate an input like following

```
element.sendKeys(valueToPut);
String readAfterEnter = element.getText();
```

`element.sendKeys(valueToPut)` worked properly
But `readAfterEnter` does not give the expected value, it is allways `null`.

Answer (score 5):

The `WebElement.getText()` method does not return the content of the user input. For this you have to use `WebElement.getAttribute("value")` (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852287/using-selenium-to-retrieve-value-of-a-html-input)).

Answer (score 3):

This code will work:

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("nameOfElement"));
String text = element.getAttribute("value");
```

The `getAttribute` method returns the value of an attribute of an HTML Tag; for example if I have an input like this:

```html
<input name = "text" type ="text" value ="Hello">
```

then this webdriver code:

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("text"));
String text = element.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(text);
```

will print out 'Hello'.