# How to get the value of input with Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

How to retrieve the field value "value" from input via the Selenium IDE (this value is variable so I want to recover its value for reuse)
My input field:

```
    <input class="myClass" type="text" value="15" name="myName">
```

When I tried the following code:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>xpath("//input[@name='myName']").getAttribute(​"value");</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${x}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I have:

```
[info] echo: xpath("//input[@name='myName']").getAttribute("value");
```

instead of:

```
15
```

thanks for help

Comment: here u go:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852287/using-selenium-to-retrieve-value-of-a-html-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem thanks @sircapsalot

solution of my problem below:

```
storeEval | window.document.getElementsByName('myName')[0].value; | x
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing javascript with the `store` method.  `getAttribute()` is a javascript method.

Also, to store an attribute, you want the `storeAttribute` method combined with CSS:

```
<tr>
  <td>storeAttribute</td>
  <td>css=input[name='myName']@value</td>
  <td>x</td>
</tr>
```

If you are trying to execute javascript, then use `storeEval`.

Comment: it does not work with Store I have : [info] echo: css=input[name='myName']/@value

Comment: Try taking out the `/`  might just be `css=input[name='myName']@value`

Comment: I have a same problem [info] echo: css=input[name='myName']@value

Answer (score 1):

storeValue works for input elements. Depending on what you need, that may be preferable to using storeEval.