# How i can get that value?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

i want to get the value in value="" which is 448CA236139FF2A5D7C40CE327779F49 and put it in variable to use it in other class

```
<input type="hidden" name="Idsession" value="448CA236139FF2A5D7C40CE327779F49" xpath="1" style="">
```

i tried

```
WebElement ids = driver.findElement(By.name("Idsession"));
String cookie=ids.getAttribute("innerText");
```

didn't worked

Comment: *getAttribute("innerText");* - why `innerText` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854392/2970947

Comment: there's no innerText right?, i just tried

Comment: thank you so much @ElliottFrisch it's worked, thanks Scary Wombat

Comment: i used                                                                                   
**String ids = driver.findElement(By.name("Idsession")).getAttribute("value");**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `String cookie = driver.findElement(By.name("Idsession")).getAttribute("value");`.

You're trying to retrieve the attribute "value", "innerText" has no relevance in that case.

Comment: Thanks @RP-01 it worked, check the comments above