# Get the text value when DOM doesn't have either title/value field

Tags: javascript, java, c#, selenium, dom

I would like to take the value using selenium from the text-box which is ready only and aria-live marked as off.

DOM as below:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="abc" type="text" role="textbox" id="sumAccount" aria-describedby="sumAccount_describedby" tabindex="0" readonly="true" data-preview="true" aria-live="off">
```

In the webpage Summary of Account field is showing the value as `"4567"` ready only field

I have tried the below code to get the value, I am getting null value always:

```
string accNumber = driver.findElement(By.id("sumAccount")).getAttribute("title");
string accNumber = driver.findElement(By.id("sumAccount")).text();
```

Can any one help me to get the value?

Comment: I would drop the tags `java` and `c#` your code is just javascript.

Comment: Please share the HTML-element structure

Comment: This can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852287/using-selenium-web-driver-to-retrieve-value-of-a-html-input

Answer (score 0):

To extract the value using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) from the `<input>` which is ready only and `aria-live="off"` you can use the following solution:

```
string accNumber = driver.findElement(By.id("sumAccount")).getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Still getting value as null "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

summaryAccount was null."

Comment: Basic question, when the DOM doesn't have attribute called "value" how selenium to get the text in the getAttribute("value").